# C++-like usage of Moose with Perl for OOP

Tags: c++, perl, oop, moose

I've been playing around with Moose, getting a feel for it. I'd like an example of pure virtual functions like in C++ but in Moose parlance (specifically in a C++-looking way). I know that even with Moose imposing a stricter model than normal Perl, there's still more than one way to do what I'm asking (via method modifiers or `SUPER::` calls). That is why I'm asking specifically for an implementation resembling C++ as much as possible. As for the "why?" of this restriction? Mostly curiosity, but also planning to port some C++ code to Perl with Moose in a way that C++-centric people could *mostly* identify with.

Comment: I moved my attempt from the question down to the answers section.

Comment: Yikes, this question is already the 3rd response when Googling for pure virtual functions in Perl with Moose. For those interested, the perlmonks discussion semi-related to this is here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=742013. They don't seem to have a concrete answer over there, either.

Comment: Probably because everyone except C++ programmers call them "methods".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of this way using roles instead of subclassing:

```
{
    package AbstractRole;
    use Moose::Role;
    requires 'stuff';  
}

{
    package Real;
    use Moose;
    with 'AbstractRole';
}
```

This will give a compilation error because Real doesn't have *stuff* defined.

Adding *stuff* method to Real will now make it work:

```
{
    package Real;
    use Moose;
    with 'AbstractRole';

    sub stuff { print "Using child function!\n" }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how it would be done if I only wanted an interface. I'm finding out through research and the discussion here that I might not be able to do _exactly_ what I'm hoping to do.

Comment: I think this gets you most of the way though. Have a chat with Moose guys at #moose on irc.perl.org or the mailing list moose@perl.org if you feel there is a benefit in extending this further.

Comment: @draegtun Yeah, I think this is the best approximation I can hope for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to take a look at Jesse Luehrs'
[MooseX::ABC](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/MooseX-ABC-0.02/lib/MooseX/ABC.pm).
It seems very similar to some of the implementations here. From the synopsis:

```
package Shape;
use Moose;
use MooseX::ABC;

requires 'draw';

package Circle;
use Moose;
extends 'Shape';

sub draw {
    # stuff
}

my $shape = Shape->new; # dies
my $circle = Circle->new; # succeeds

package Square;
use Moose;
extends 'Shape'; # dies, since draw is unimplemented
```

I know that Jesse is a C++ programmer during the day.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely check that out!

Comment: Updated link from pointing at version 0.20 to the current version.  Version 0.30 added subclassing abstract base classes with further abstract classes.

Answer (score 2):

It appears I can't do exactly what I want with Moose, but I can come very close with Roles. Here is the information from the Moose manual [entry](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.89/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod) for Roles:

> **Roles Versus Abstract Base Classes**
>
> If you are familiar with the concept
>   of abstract base classes in other
>   languages, you may be tempted to use
>   roles in the same way.
>
> You can define an "interface-only"
>   role, one that contains just a list of
>   required methods.
>
> However, any class which consumes this
>   role must implement all of the
>   required methods, either directly or
>   through inheritance from a parent. You
>   cannot delay the method requirement
>   check so that they can be implemented
>   by future subclasses.
>
> Because the role defines the required
>   methods directly, adding a base class
>   to the mix would not achieve anything.
>   We recommend that you simply consume
>   the interface role in each class which
>   implements that interface.

Comment: snap!  Your answer appeared just as I was tidying up mine ;-)

Comment: @draegtun Funny how that happens! Your answer is really helpful, especially for people who are looking to implement interfaces with Moose. I just came up with an oddball question that I'm finding through further research might not have a deterministic answer. I'm still trying to decide if this is because I fully didn't understand the area before asking, or if Moose is missing this feature ;)

Comment: Hmm.  Is it just me or is that help actually not very helpful?  It seems to say 'if you want to implement an abstract class with a role it doesn't work because they're not the same thing; instead, *look over there, a flying pig*!  I'd still be interested in either (a) how do do a hierarchy of abstract classes (specifically if MooseX::ABC is considered good or not) or alternatively (b) why ABCs are bad for Moose programs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is was my attempt (without Roles, for information on Roles see the other answers):

```
package Abstract;
use Moose;

sub stuff;

package Real;
use Moose;
extends 'Abstract';

override 'stuff' => sub { print "Using child function!\n"; }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, but it seems like you want `Abstract` to be an abstract base class and the `stuff` method (not function) to be pure virtual. Just writing `sub stuff {}` immediately violates that. So, base class method should probably be `sub stuff { croak }`.

Comment: @Sinan I was going for something like C++'s: virtual void stuff() = 0;

Comment: @Sinan I have two concerns with adding the croak to stuff: 1) it didn't compile for me and 2) you could argue that croak is a form of implementation, which (unless I'm misinterpreting the definition of pure virtual functions) is exactly the opposite of what I'm going for. I'm editing sub stuff { ; } to be sub stuff;

Comment: `croak` comes from Carp, and must be imported.  Add 'use Carp qw(croak);` to any package you wish to use it in.

Comment: @daotoad Wow...thanks for pointing out a silly oversight on my part. I let my vim syntax highlighting go to my head!

Comment: @Kyle Walsh the `croak` was a hack making sure no code invoking `Abstract->stuff` would appear to work whereas an empty sub body would not prevent that.

Comment: Moose imports confess() for you so s/croak/confess/ and it will just work. However as was *just* pointed out in #moose sub stuff { confess; } doesn't do _compile_ time checking ... the Role and MX::ABC solutions do.

Comment: @perigrin: From the above answers, looks to me like MX::ABC does construction-time checking, not call-time (both are run-time not compile-time, though).